# New Flutter project not functional workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

The bottom bar in VS Code does not show flutter as running, and [this tutorial page](https://flutter.io/using-ide-vscode/#selecting-a-target-device) follows with a note about not having workspaces included. No answer as to how to include it, though.

That is why I have come here. How can I set the folder up as a proper workspace? Adding it to a workspace from the File > menu doesn't help.

Comment: Just open the folder containing your `pubspec.yaml` in vscode. That's enough

Comment: Thank you, Rémi!

Answer (score 0):

When opening a Dart project we'll look for a `pubspec.yaml` file in the root folder that contains an `sdk: flutter` line to decide whether to go into "Flutter mode".

This works the same for multiple workspace folders, but the root of each will be checked and if any single project references Flutter then we'll use the Flutter SDK for them all.

If you want to open a parent folder you could also add the Flutter project directly as a workspace folder to ensure it goes into Flutter more (though you'll end up with the folder showing twice in the Explorer until VS Code implements [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45470)).